# using a texture with indices and vertices

Tags: xna, c#

I've written this down on paper and tried to understand how the triangles of each cube are created, but I can't get my texture drawn on my cube properly. I don't know if it's the texuture coordinates of each face of my cube, or the order in which I create the cube from my vertices, but I only see two sides correctly and the rest are gray.

[image]

```
    private void SetUpFrontFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
    {

        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector2(0, 1)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector2(0, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, 0), new Vector2(1, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector2(1, 1)));
    }

    private void SetUpBackFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
    {
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector2(0, 1)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, -1), new Vector2(0, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector2(1, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, -1), new Vector2(1, 1)));
    }

    private void SetUpLeftFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
    {
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector2(0, 1)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, -1), new Vector2(0, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector2(1, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector2(1, 1)));
    }

    private void SetUpRightFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
    {
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector2(0, 1)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, 0), new Vector2(0, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector2(1, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, -1), new Vector2(1, 1)));
    }

    private void SetUpTopFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
    {
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector2(0, 1)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, -1), new Vector2(0, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector2(1, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1)));
    }

    private void SetUpBottomFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
    {
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector2(0, 1)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, -1), new Vector2(1, 1)));
        vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0)));
    }

    private void SetUpIndicesAndVertices(float x, float y, float z, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices, List<short> indices)
    {
        short verticesStart = (short)vertices.Count;

        Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);

        SetUpFrontFace(cubeInChunkPosition, vertices);
        SetUpBackFace(cubeInChunkPosition, vertices);

        SetUpRightFace(cubeInChunkPosition, vertices);
        SetUpLeftFace(cubeInChunkPosition, vertices);

        SetUpTopFace(cubeInChunkPosition, vertices);
        SetUpBottomFace(cubeInChunkPosition, vertices);
```

All my vertices being built. I think the texture coordinates are correct. They start from the top left corner rotating clockwise around the whole face.

```
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 0));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 2));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 3));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 0));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 1));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 2));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 1));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 5));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 6));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 1));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 6));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 2));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 2));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 6));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 7));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 2));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 7));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 3));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 4));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 7));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 6));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 4));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 6));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 5));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 1));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 4));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 5));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 1));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 0));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 4));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 0));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 7));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 4));

        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 0));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 3));
        indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 7));
```

The indices. I don't know why this is happening. I've messed around with the Texture values and have gotten textures to show on all sides, but they always come out skewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are being specified anti-clockwise. They should match the x and y coords of your first face.

```
private void SetUpFrontFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
{

    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0)));
    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector2(0, 1)));
    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1)));
    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0)));
}
```

EDIT:

Also your vertices in `SetUpBackFace` and `SetUpBottomFace` are being supplied in anti-clockwise.

```
private void SetUpBackFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
{
     vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector2(0, 0)));
     vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, -1), new Vector2(0, 1)));
     vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector2(1, 1)));
     vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 1, -1), new Vector2(1, 0)));
}

private void SetUpBottomFace(Vector3 cubeInChunkPosition, List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices)
{
    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0)));
    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector2(0, 1)));
    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(1, 0, -1), new Vector2(1, 1)));
    vertices.Add(new VertexPositionTexture(cubeInChunkPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector2(1, 0)));
}
```

EDIT 2:

You need to re-evaluate your index list:

```
    // Front face
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 0));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 2));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 3));

    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 0));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 1));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 2));

    // Back face
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 4));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 6));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 7));

    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 4));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 5));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 6));

    // Left face
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 8));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 10));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 11));

    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 8));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 9));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 10));

    // Right face
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 12));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 14));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 15));

    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 12));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 13));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 14));

    // Top face
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 16));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 18));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 19));

    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 16));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 17));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 18));

    // Bottom face
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 20));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 22));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 23));

    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 20));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 21));
    indices.Add((short)(verticesStart + 22));
```

Comment: That worked for the most part. 2 faces are still completely gray

Comment: I figured out that its in my SetUpBackFace method. If I change the texture values, everything turns gray except 2 sides

Comment: Yes you're right, I've edited the answer.

Comment: That actually made things worse for some reason. Now the actual sides of the cube are wacky

Comment: Yes, your index list was very bizarre. Edited.

Comment: Thats funny because someone on this site helped me with the index list. I tried drawing it out to make sense of it but it didn't help. But everything works fine now. Thanks!!

Comment: Did it work? Well you are creating 24 vertices but you are only referencing 8 max. Now, you can do that as there are only 8 vertices in a cube however, in this instance it does not match your vertex list as you are adding them to the array quad by quad.

Comment: My plan eventually is to do some face culling with my SetUp methods. Shouldn't the indices list only need values from 0 to 7 if the vertices can be shared?

Comment: Yes vertices can be shared as I mentioned in the previous comment, but you should also set up a unique vertex array for this too.